# How do I enable the 'trimmed' policy in Jinja2?

Tags: django, internationalization, jinja2

I am trying to enable the trimmed keyword for all {% trans %} blocks in Jinja2. I have added `env.policies['ext.i18n.trimmed'] = True` (found here: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#policies) in my environment configuration, but nothing happens. In my project I am using Babel with Jinja2 and Django to extract messages.

Here is my environment configuration:

```
def environment(**options):
     env = Environment(
         **options,
         extensions=[
             'compressor.contrib.jinja2ext.CompressorExtension',
             'jinja2.ext.autoescape',
             'sass_processor.jinja2.ext.SassSrc',
             'jinja2.ext.i18n',
         ]
     }

     env.policies['ext.i18n.trimmed'] = True
     env.install_gettext_callables(gettext=gettext, ngettext=ngettext)

     env.globals.update(globals)
     env.filters.update(filters)
     return env
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how useful this will be over a year later, but if anyone else runs into this problem, you can extract with the policy by adding

```
trimmed = True
```

to your babel mapping configuration.

I'm not sure if this is documented anywhere, but the entry point described in the documentation for [Babel integration](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/integration/#babel-integration) checks for the string "trimmed" to enable the environment policy [if you look at the source code](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/main/src/jinja2/ext.py#L835).

Comment: Brilliant! Works like a charm and ended my extended search for a solution.